# Highlight cells using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I want some cells to highlight when for example cell A1 is "test1".
I tried to use conditional formatting but it only highlights that particular cell and nog a variety of other cells.
I'm not a very experienced excel user but i think it is a simple VBA code to do this.

I hope somebody can help me here.
Tx

Comment: Did you select all the cells when applying the conditional format?

Comment: It can be very easy conditional formatting. Don't use VBA for this.

Comment: If you're after some VBA code then I'm afraid this isn't the right place. If you want help with your conditional formatting please show us your rule and what you've tried so far. Likewise if you want help with getting some VBA to work, show us what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

Few steps only:

- Create new conditional formatting rule: `=$A$1="test1"`
- Choose your formatting
- Choose range for conditional formatting rule and hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to select multiple cells (see below)

[image]